# List<T> item remove problem

Tags: c#, many-to-many, relational-database

Don't be scared of the extensive code. The problem is general. I just provided the code to understand the problem better.

I am trying to find out a standard approach of manipulating tables with many-to-many relationships. And I am almost done. Here `Teacher` and `Course` have M:M relationship. I have designed my classes as follows:

`Teacher` - class:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string TeacherName{get;set;}
    private List<Course> _items = null;
    public List<Course> Items
    {
        get 
        {   if (_items == null) {_items = Course.GetCoursesByTeacherID(_ID);}
            return _items;
        }
        set {_items = value;}
    }
    public int Save() 
    {   //...
        CourseTeacher.DeleteCoursesByTeacherID(tc, id);
        CourseTeacher.SaveCoursesWithTeacherID(tc, id, this.Items);
        //...
    }
    public bool Update()
    {   //...
        CourseTeacher.DeleteCoursesByTeacherID(tc, this.ID);
        CourseTeacher.SaveCoursesWithTeacherID(tc, this.ID, this.Items);
        //...
    }
    public static Teacher Get(int id)
    {   //...
        item.Items = CourseTeacher.GetCoursesByTeacherID(tc, item.ID);//...
    }
    public static List<Teacher> Get()
    {   //...
        items[i].Items = CourseTeacher.GetCoursesByTeacherID(tc, items[i].ID);//...
    }
    public static List<Teacher> GetTeachersByCourseID(int id)
    {   //...
        items = CourseTeacher.GetTeachersByCourseID(tc, id);//...
    }
    public bool Delete()
    {   //...
        CourseTeacher.DeleteCoursesByTeacherID(tc, this.ID);//...
    }
}
```

`Course` is absolutely similar to `Teacher` - class. And the mapping class is as follows:

```
public class CourseTeacher
{
    public int CourseID{get;set;}
    public int TeacherID{get;set;}  
    public static void SaveCoursesWithTeacherID(TransactionContext tc, int teacherID, List<Course> items){}
    public static void SaveTeachersWithCourseID(TransactionContext tc, int courseID, List<Teacher> items){}
    private void Save(TransactionContext tc){}
    public static void DeleteCoursesByTeacherID(TransactionContext tc, int teacherID){}
    public static void DeleteTeachersByCourseID(TransactionContext tc, int courseID){}
    public static List<Teacher> GetTeachersByCourseID(TransactionContext tc, int courseID){}
    public static List<Course> GetCoursesByTeacherID(TransactionContext tc, int teacherID){}
}
```

Now my problem is, this code is not working?

```
Teacher professorXyz = Teacher.Get(2);                        
Course cpp = Course.Get(3);
Course java = Course.Get(2);
professorXyz.Items.Remove(cpp);
professorXyz.Items.Remove(java);
professorXyz.Update();
```

This is not working because it is not probably finding a match or get accessor is returning readonly List.

How should I refactor my Teacher/Course - class to achieve this?

No exception. No problem with persistence code. Items are not being removed.

why `professorXyz.Items.Contains(cpp);` is returning false?

What to check for?

Comment: How is it not working? No exception but the data are not persisted correctly?

Comment: +1 for this post as many developers will encounter similar problem (some w/o realizing it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a direct answer, but...

Your design is very (very) Relational. That makes persisting to a DB easier but you do not have a proper OO model. Maybe you should consider using DataTables in a DataSet and reap the benefits of the Relation class.

---

To take a shot:

```
Teacher professorXyz = Teacher.Get(2);                        
Course cpp = Course.Get(3);
```

I suspect that the cpp course is being loaded twice, and that there are 2 instances of that course in memory. A very bad consequence of your design. By default, those 2 instances will not be equal and that is why `Remove` does not work.  You could overload `Equals`, `==` and `GethashCode` but that is [*not recommended* for mutable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx).
What you really need is a design where for a given Teacher or Course there never exists more than 1 instance in memory.

Re Comment: A MxM relation in OO looks like:

```
class Teacher
{
   public readonly List<Course> Courses = ...;
}

class Course
{
   public readonly List<Teacher> Teachers = ...;
}
```

This will take a little more work to write to a DB but it solves a lot of other problems.

Comment: -1 for recommending DataSet and DataTable in a world where NHibernate, Castle ActiveRecord, Subsonic and Linq-to-SQL are all free...

Comment: Dylan, DataTable would not be my 1st choice but it is a very _relational_ and _simple_ option. Your list is all O/R Mappers.

Comment: @Henk, can you please elaborate on override Equals not recommended for mutable types?

Comment: sorry, if I'm wrong, but we're talking about value equality, not reference; so, while your approach is far better, just overriding Equals can solve his/her immediate problem. Do you agree, Henk? TIA

Comment: It would solve the Remove problem, but would still leave multiple instances/entity. It would also open the door for a set of new problems.

Comment: nice to hear that, Henk; I learned a lot today by reading your posts on subject, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do? Your sample looks like you want to build a relational database table implemented in C#.

If you want to have an OO representation then get rid of the entire CourseTeacher class. That has absolutely nothing to do with OO.

Comment: @Foxfire, thanks for your answer. It is actually a helper class to manage Teacher and Course M:M relationship. Without this class it will be hard to manage data-manipulation. You are very much welcome to share your approach. And what about my actual question?

Comment: So just to clarify: Do you want a relational Database? Then what are you trying to do exactly? And what is your question? "I am trying to find out a standard approach of manipulating tables with many-to-many relationships" or "Why is my code not working". And in advance: The current code has nothing to do with any standard approach of n:m table matching.

Comment: OK. Let me know the standard approach of managing M:M relational classes. And also why professorXyz.Items.Contains(cpp); is returning false?

Comment: I would assume that you somehow directly generate the objects from the database. Then Course cpp = Course.Get(3); creates a ccp object but when you call professorXyz.Items.Remove(cpp); then ccp is not part of that list because you may create a new list from the database when professorXyz.Items gets called. Then you have two objects (obviously two objects with the same content and id, but in OO still two DIFFERENT objects)

Comment: OK. I understand. How to get around with this?

Comment: A) Throw the entire thing away and do something OO. Look at DataSets, relational mappers or put the logic into seperate pieces if you want to do it by hand.

Comment: B) If you want to keep your current implementation you would have to override Equals and GetHashcode for all your objects and test for equality based on the database ID. Please note that this then has nothing to do with OO anymore.

Answer (score 1):

seems you already solved this problem, but consider following code where I overrode `bool Equals`; C# couldn't knew how to compare your new `cpp` instance with another instance in your `List<Course>`, so we need to tell it by creating a more specialized `Equals` method:

```
class Teacher
{
    private List<Course> items = new List<Course>();

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Items { get { return items; } }
}

class Course
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()       { return base.GetHashCode(); }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { return Equals(obj as Course); }
    public bool Equals(Course another)
    {
        return another != null && this.ID.Equals(another.ID);
    }
} 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Teacher teacher = new Teacher { ID = 2 };
    teacher.Items.AddRange(
        new Course[] { 
            new Course{ ID = 2 },       // java
            new Course{ ID = 3 } });    // cpp

    Course cpp = new Course { ID = 3 }; // previous problem: another instance
    teacher.Items.Contains(cpp);        // now returns true
    teacher.Items.Remove(cpp);          // now returns true
}
```

Comment: But as you see one of the guys said that this is not recommended. Why did he think that?

Comment: @JMSA: follow our discussion on Henk answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584540/listt-item-remove-problem/1584604#1584604

Answer (score 1):

Henk is correct; your design is very, very relational. For this sort of scenario, though, you're better off focusing on behaviour in your objects, and using an object-relational mapping (ORM) tool to translate between your objects and your database.

ADO.NET's DataTable and DataSet don't really offer object-relational mapping capabilities; because they're so tightly coupled to the underlying database schema, they force you to think in terms of columns, tables and relations, when you really want to be thinking in terms of teachers and courses.

I would seriously recommend looking at [Castle ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html) for this scenario. It uses the same approach as your example - static Teacher.Get() to retrieve an instance, myTeacher.Save() to save your changes - but there's a LOT of necessary complexity that your example is missing, and using an ORM framework will allow you to ignore this complexity and focus on your own project's requirements.

Here's [an example of many-many associations](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/relations/hasandbelongs.html) from the Castle ActiveRecord documentation that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding and removing done within the Teacher Class?

```
public class Teacher
{
        //.... Original implementations
    public bool AddCourse(Course course) {
        if(_items.Contains(course)) return false;

        _items.Add(course);
        return true;
    }

        // similarly for remove course

}
```

Comment: let me try it. I shall let u know my answer with in minutes.

Comment: No it is not working. Always returning false. Object is not being matched. What else to check for?

Comment: Could be the comparator for the course object. You might need to implement GetHashCode() overrides to return say the CourseID for the method to identify the Course object to be the matching one.

Comment: And have you verified that your loading is working, so that those courses are there at all? Start with inspecting Items.Count in the debugger.

Comment: On second thought, maybe RemoveCourse(int CourseID) works better.